# Use Jinja2 template with ini host file

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ini

I am creating an ansible role, that would allow users to list the desired groups to create and ipset off of

My first thought was to use the ini lookup plugin but that did not work at all. I need to do some regex, with some variables in host line, and i got the template all figured out for that, but what i don't have figured out is below.

Given an `.ini` file, and a list of groups, I'd like to make a template that would print out all the host lines in the group. I can't seem to find a way to print lines after a match variable, until a blank line.

so for example with `inventory.ini`and `group_1` and `group_3`

```
[group_1]
host1 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host2 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host3 ansible_host=X.X.X.X

[group_2]
host4 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host5 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host6 ansible_host=X.X.X.X

[group_3]
host7 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host8 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host9 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
```

would template to:

```
host1 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host2 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host3 ansible_host=X.X.X.
host7 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host8 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
host9 ansible_host=X.X.X.X
```

Currently I use the file lookup plugin to add our inventory files to a variable, and use that variable in the template files. The example below, works for all hosts in the inventory files.

```
{% for line in inventory.split('\n') %}
{% if 'ipv4_public=' in line %}
add {{ ipset_name }} {{  line | regex_search( '(?<=ipv4_public=).[^ ]*' ) }}
{% if 'ansible_host=' in line %}
add {{ ipset_name }} {{  line | regex_search( '(?<=ansible_host=).[^ ]*' ) }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is much simpler to iterate over the group names of inventory like `{% for host in groups['group1'] %}`. Have you tried it?

Comment: To add up to @seshadri_c : loop over your inventory and use the [`hostvars` dictionnary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html) to get vars from the desired host.

Comment: I was told by my team that looping over host vars took far to long when running playbook. So I am using regex to snip out the ansible_host IP which runs a lot faster

Comment: I suggest you try it for yourself and decide if what was told by your team makes sense or not.

Answer (score 1):

To follow my comment, in a quickNdirty nutshell, just to put you on track:

Edit: I took for granted you will provide a `host_groups` var which will be a list of all groups you want to work on e.g.

```yaml
host_groups:
  - group1
  - group3
```

And the (example, untested) template:

```
{% for host in (host_groups | map('extract', groups) | flatten | unique) %}
{% if hostvars[host].ipv4_public is defined %}
add {{ ipset_name }} {{ hostvars[host].ipv4_public }}
{% endif %}
add {{ ipset_name }} {{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }}
```

Note that the last line will return the `inventory_name` if `ansible_host` is not explicitly defined in your inventory. Adapt to your exact needs.

Comment: The issue is I don't know what groups will used in the future, so i have a variable 'host_groups' which is a list of group names that can be used for making the ipset. It could be group_1, or group_2 and group_45.

Comment: This is typically something that should not go in a volatile comment but in an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67059655/edit) of your question, with an [MCVE](/help/mcve) showing what your are trying to do with code rather than words trying to explain it. Updated the answer to fit this new requirement.